# Regex to remove everything from div

Tags: python, regex

```
html = 
<div>
<p style="color: #555555; margin-top:32px;">
    Sent
   <span>
    by
    <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #875A7B;" href="http://www.example.com">
    <span>YourCompany</span>
   </a>

</span>
    using
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.odoo.com?utm_source=db&amp;utm_medium=email" 
        style="text-decoration:none; color: #875A7B;">Odoo</a>.
      </p>
```

I have this regex expression

```
html = re.sub(
            'using' + "(.*)[\r\n]*(.*)>" + 'Odoo' + r"</a>", "", html,
        )
```

and I get result

```
html =
<div> 
<p style="color: #555555; margin-top:32px;">
Sent
<span>
by
<a style="text-decoration:none; color: #875A7B;" href="http://www.example.com">
    <span>YourCompany</span>
</a>

</span>
.
</p>
  </div>
```

but how can I update my regex to remove all from `<p` tag. Basicaly i need empty `<div` here but only if `<p` tag includes words `Sent` and `by`

Comment: Consider using a parser (e.g. `BeautifulSoup`) and `xpath` queries instead.

Comment: [One doesn't simply handle HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/770830).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
With the same pattern, you could first check if `<p>` contains `"Sent"` and `"by"`.

```py
pattern = re.compile("<p(.*\n)*.*</p>")
p = re.search(pattern, html).group(0)

if "Sent" in p and "by" in p:
    html = re.sub(pattern, "", html)
```

#### Old answer

This should work: `html = re.sub("<p(.*\n)*.*<\/p>", "", html)`.

Comment: I updated my question, there is one more clause

Comment: actually your code give this error TypeError: argument of type 're.Match' is not iterable

Comment: @Chaban33 I could not reproduce this error. Also, I am not iterating over any `Match` object, so I don't think the error comes from my code. You can update your question with some more information about the error and where it occurred, so that I can look over it.